# notifyDataSetChange() Is not working in adapter

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm working with Android's new RecyclerView but I can't get my custom adapter to refresh whenever I call one of the "notify" methods.

I've tried calling notifyDataSetChanged, notifyItemRangeInserted and notifyItemInserted and none of them seem to work.

i am getting list size is correct but **recycleview only set 10 item** when i scroll the page api is called.upadted list size is 20 but not display other 10 items.i want to display all item in list please help me....

**this is my adapter** :

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<NotificationDataItem> mData;


public NotificationAdapter(Context context, List<NotificationDataItem> mData) {
    this.context=context;
    this.mData=mData;
}


@NotNull
@Override
public NotificationAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    AdapterNotificationBinding adapterNotificationBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.adapter_notification,
            parent, false);
    return new NotificationAdapter.ViewHolder(adapterNotificationBinding);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NotNull NotificationAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (mData.get(position).getName()!=null&&!mData.get(position).getName().isEmpty()){
        holder.binding.tvUserNotification.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
    }
    if (mData.get(position).getBody()!=null&&!mData.get(position).getBody().isEmpty()){
        holder.binding.tvUserNotificationBody.setText(mData.get(position).getBody());
    }
    if (mData.get(position).getCreatedAt()!=null&&!mData.get(position).getCreatedAt().isEmpty()){
        holder.binding.tvTime.setText(mData.get(position).getCreatedAt());
    }
    if (mData.get(position).getAvatar()!=null){
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(mData.get(position).getAvatar())
                .circleCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_white_speaker)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_white_speaker)
                .into(holder.binding.ivUser);
    }
    /*type => 0 = comment, 1 = like, 2 = unlike, 3 = comment reply

   */
    if (mData.get(position).getType()!=null){
        switch (mData.get(position).getType()) {
            case "0":case "3":
                holder.binding.ivEditProfileImage.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorgray), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                holder.binding.ivEditProfileImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_comment_filled));
                break;
            case "1":
                holder.binding.ivEditProfileImage.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorgray), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                holder.binding.ivEditProfileImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_like_filled));

                break;
            case "2":
                holder.binding.ivEditProfileImage.setRotation(180);
                holder.binding.ivEditProfileImage.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorgray), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                holder.binding.ivEditProfileImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_like_filled));
                break;
            /*case "3":
                holder.binding.ivEditProfileImage.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorgray), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                holder.binding.ivEditProfileImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_comment_filled));
                break;*/
        }

    }


    holder.binding.llNotification.setOnClickListener(v->{
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("postId", mData.get(position).getPostId());
        context.startActivity(intent);
    });

    holder.binding.ivUser.setOnClickListener(v->{
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtherUserProfileActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("userId", mData.get(position).getUserId());
        context.startActivity(intent);
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
public void updateList(List<NotificationDataItem> mNotification) {
    this.mData.addAll(mNotification);
    Log.d("updateList", "updateList:"+mData.size());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d("updateList123", "updateList123:"+mData.size());
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    AdapterNotificationBinding binding;

    public ViewHolder(AdapterNotificationBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}
```

}

this is how i attach:

```
  adapter = new NotificationAdapter(  getActivity(),response.body().getData().getData() );
                                    
                                        if (page == 1) {
                                            binding.rvNotification.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        } else {
                                            adapter.updateList(response.body().getData().getData());
        
                                        }
```

Comment: your adapter looks fine, can you show how do you create it and attach to `RecyclerView` and also how/when do you update its data? I'm assuming that logs put in `update` methods are showing bigger number than `RecyclerView` contains items?

Comment: @snachmsm yes... i edited my question

Comment: `this.notifyDataSetChanged();` or `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are creating new `adapter` instance every time instead of updating already created and attached to `RecyclerView`. move your creation code into `if` for creating and attaching adapter only once, then in `else` you can update it (same reference, same object)

```
if (page == 1) {
    adapter = new NotificationAdapter(getActivity(), response.body().getData().getData());
    binding.rvNotification.setAdapter(adapter);
} else {
    adapter.updateList(response.body().getData().getData());
}
```

another approach would be to create new adapter every time but then you also must call `setAdapter(adapter);` (new one). updating already existing one is better approach

Answer (score 3):

i got the solution when page 2 is called i initialized new adapter so i get the same data in recyclerview so i try this:

```
  if (page == 1) {
 adapter =new NotificationAdapter(getActivity(),response.body().getData().getData());
                                    binding.rvNotification.setAdapter(adapter);
                                } else {
                                    adapter.updateList(response.body().getData().getData());

                                }
```

Comment: upvoting as you found solution earlier than me (posted answer faster) :) good luck!